Where does Sellars speak about chess?
I remember from an undergraduate course that Sellars introduces his inferentialism with reference to the analogy of chess figures. I think the idea is roughly that the meaning of a word is more like the role of a chess figure, than like something conferred to it by a mental act. But where does he actually speak about this? I have trouble finding out.
Thanks!

Maybe useful Wilfird Sellars, Some Reflections on Language Games (1954)

Such a point of view completely neglects the fact that the mental acts are part of the game of how the piece/word is used. The mental acts determine when and how the word will be used, on at least an equal basis as the visible social communication. They are not something that can be neglected or dismissed just because they are less outwardly visible. The mental circumstances under which the brain thinks a word bear the same relation to the word as the social circumstances under which people communicate the word. They're both parts of "the game."

Sorry for the confusion, did not want to imply that the mental is not part of the game. The idea is more that meaning is more than someone just making a sound and thinking "this means XYZ". That being said, my own view is that the mind is also just a symbol processing system, i.e. societies are symbol processing systems that consist of smaller interacting symbol processing systems

Mauro Allengranza commented:

Maybe useful Wilfird Sellars, Some Reflections on Language Games (1954) –
Mauro ALLEGRANZA

Well, having just read the paper, I can certify that he certainly uses the analogy of chess in relation to language in the article. It's a fascinating attempt to move from a logical to a psychological perspective of "language rules" by shifting the emphasis by putting forth an argument of infinite regress regarding what "rules" are and where they come from. This is of course is an extension of later LW's argument about the Sprachspiel in PI. From the paper:

whereas obeying rules involves using the language in which the rules are formulated, conforming to rules does not, so that whereas the thesis put in terms of obeying the rules leads to a vicious regress, it ceases to do so

There a broader explanation in the IEP's article on Sellars:

The famous analogy used here is that a word’s meaning is akin to a chess piece, where what makes a particular chess piece the one it is, say a pawn versus a bishop, is what can be done with it, how it can be used. Words, in turn, are used to help make inferences, to reason. The contributing role a word makes to such reasoning gives us its functional role, and thus its meaning. With this as the model, we can now say that thinking is done with “inner elements”, where the functional role these elements play in inferences made in thinking parallels the patterns of use of their public linguistic counterparts. Since what matters is the functional role played by these elements, not by what they are made of (as is the case with chess pieces), Sellars emerges as an early (if not the earliest contemporary) functionalist in the philosophy of mind. Thinking is understood as the counterpart to overt linguistic behavior, which for Sellars means the use of linguistic items in the service of inferences, the meanings of the items given by the role they play in those inferences.

I can also say that the analogy is not present in perhaps his most famous work Empiricism & the Philosophy of Mind. If you think it might be in his other works, you won't get anywhere with the IEP bibliography. The SEP, however, has a substantial bibliography of Wilfrid Sellars (SEP). There are some other potential candidates such as “Language, Rules and Behavior,” In John Dewey: Philosopher of Science and Freedom, S. Hook (ed.), New York: Dial Press, 1949: 289–315; reprinted in PPPW: 129–55. and “Language as Thought and Communication,” Philosophy and Phenomenological Research 29 1969: 506–27; reprinted in EPH: 93–117; ISR:: 57–80.
